# How to compare NSString with NSString nil Value?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, if-statement, ios7

I'm new to iOS development. I get an error when I compare `NSString` with `NSString` nil value. It is not working in if condition.

my code is:

```
  NSDictionary *responseFromJSON = [JSON objectForKey:@"response"];
  NSString *strResponseMsg = [responseFromJSON objectForKey:@"104"];   
  if ([strResponseMsg isEqualToString:nil])
     {
         NSLog(@"login Invalid");
     }
     else
     {
         NSLog(@"login success");
     }
```

Comment: no mention @bhavdip patel

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do like this,

```
    NSString * string = nil;
if (string!=nil &&  // not nil, means 0x0 object
    string.length>0 && // at leaset one character should exists
    [string isEqual:[NSNull null]]) { // to avoid 'null' in string

    // valid string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this,

```
if ([yourString isEqual:[NSNull null]])
{
  //your code goes here
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use below

```
NSString *strResponseMsg = [responseFromJSON objectForKey:@"104"];   
if (!strResponseMsg)
{
    NSLog(@"login Invalid");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"login success");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the NSString whether it's nil or empty.
You just need to do something like that:

```
if (strResponseMsg.length) {}
```

Because it will not go inside if the *strResponseMsg* is nil or empty. It will only go inside when *strResponseMsg* is not nil and no empty.